# JQuery monitorando sequencias de teclas

Tags: jquery, código-de-barras, code128

Estou fazendo um formulário, onde os dados são inseridos através do escaneamento de códigos de barra (padrão code 128).

Após escanear cada valor, o escâner de mão já está configurado para dar um `<TAB>` e ir para o próximo campo, tornando bem prático no uso repetitivo deste formulário.

Porém o **ENTER** tem que ser via teclado. Perdendo aquela sequencia de cadastros ágeis.
Então pensei em criar um código de barras, com uma sequencia de valores no qual através de uma função javascript eu entenderia que aquilo é um sinal de **ENTER**, ex:
No código seria '++++++' assim ao escanear esse valor o **JQuery** entenderia essa sequencia e faria o submit do form.

**Mas infelizmente não funcionou, pois o JQuery na minha função só consegue entender a primeira tecla e não a sequencia.**

```
$(document).bind('keydown', '+++++', function (e) {
    alerte('teste');
    $('form#myForm').submit();
});
```

Ou existe como fazer um código de barras especial para envio?

**Exemplo no Fiddle**
https://fiddle.jshell.net/tvdpL6xe/

Comment: Não entendi o que tentou fazer, se você vai criar um codigo de barra, não basta verifica-lo e executar a função `ENTER` baseado nisso?

Comment: tentei fazer um código de barras com a sequencia +++++ ou qualquer outro caracter..e ai o jquery entenderia o KeyDown e acionaria um submit..vou tentar editar para deixar mais claro

Comment: Não basta após o .blur() dar um trigger('click') no elemento alvo ?

Comment: Só uma curiosidade: quando o scanner lê as barras e joga os números pra dentro do input, qual o evento que o script detecta (change, keydown, keyup....)? Obg!

Comment: então o scaner de código de barras, funciona como um teclado usb..vc escaneia o código e ele joga a string no campo com foco.. sendo o mesmo processo do teclado, keydown, keyup. etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode criar uma variável global para ir concatenando e comparando, quando for igual você executa e limpa, quando houver um caractere diferente de `+` você também limpa, segue a baixo um exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var codigo = "";
  $(document).bind('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.charCode === 43) {
      for (var i = 0; i < codigo.length; i++) {
        if (codigo.substr(i, 1) != '+') {
          codigo = "";
          break;
        }
      }

      codigo = codigo + '+';

      if (codigo == '+++++') {
        alert("Vai enviar!");
        $('#teste').submit();
        codigo = "";
      }
    } else {
      codigo = "";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<form id='teste' method='post'>
  <input type='text' id='campo1'><br>
  <input type='text' id='campo2'><br>
  <input type='text' id='campo3'><br>
  <input type='submit' value='enviar'>
</form>
```

Pelo evento `keydown` não estava dando para verificar qual a tecla foi pressionada, no evento `keypress` deu certinho.

Comment: pelo visto não deu certo, primeiro que vi que ele entra naquele if do for mesmo para teclas não iguais a +, e depois mesmo digitando+++++

Comment: O `for` só verifica se a variável `codigo` contém algum caractere diferente de `+`, se houver, ele limpa a variável.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/tvdpL6xe/

Comment: Fazendo os testes no `JSFiddle` percebi que quando executamos `"++".substring(1, 1)` ele retorna vazio, por isso estava entrando no `if`. Mas se executarmos `"++".substr(1, 1)` ele retorna "+", então com `substr` ao invés de `substring` o código irá funcionar. Vou alterar na resposta também.

Comment: agora acho que ficou perfeito!

Comment: ao digitar quaisquer dados ele diz que vai enviar

Comment: Fiz duas alterações, a primeira foi mudar de `keydown` para `keypress` e a segunda foi colocar um `if` antes de executar o código.

Answer (score 4):

Uma outra forma de resolver o seu problema sem precisar configurar um código especial seria verificar se todos os inputs do `form` estão preenchidos e caso sim, fazer o submit.

```
$(document).bind('focusout', 'input', function (e) { // Podemos verificar no blur por que o leitor está configurado para dara um <TAB> ap
  var naoPreenchidos = $('form').find('input[type="text"]').filter(function() {
    return this.value === '';
  });
  if (naoPreenchidos.length === 0) {
    alert('teste vai postar');
    $('form#myForm').submit();
  }
});
```

Ma se preferir verificar o código você pode checar a sequência no evento de `keyup` ao invés de `keydown`, dessa forma você consegue acessar o valor do input e comparar com o código que você configurar.

```js
$(document).bind('keyup', function (e) {
  var codigo = $(e.target).val();
  if (codigo === '+++++') {
    alert('teste vai postar');
    $('form#myForm').submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="teste" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="campo1" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="campo2" /><br>
  <input type="text" id="campo3" /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: o código funcionou, porém quando coloco no meu formulário ele não faz o submit e da um erro no meu jquery.validation jquery.validate.js:786 Uncaught TypeError: Globalize.parseNumber is
Sendo que se eu clicasse no botão submit ele enviaria ou validaria o formulário

Comment: Você tentou com qual solução?

Answer (score 3):

> Após escanear cada valor, o escâner de mão já está configurado para dar um *<TAB>* e ir para o próximo campo, tornando bem prático no uso repetitivo deste formulário.

Então creio que a solução seria como já dito nos comentários veja.

Vamos supor que o último campo tem o atributo *ID* definido como `codigo`, ele é o último a ser preenchido e o último a ser dado *TAB*, sendo assim é o último a perder o foco.

```
// Quando o input[id='codigo'] perde o foco
$("#codigo").on('blur', function(e) {
    var valor = $(this).val();
    // Verifica os cinco últimos caracteres
    if (valor.slice(-5) === '+++++') {
        // Se é igual executa uma ação
        $("form").submit();
    }
});
```

#### Veja funcionando

```js
$("#codigo").on('blur', function(e) {
  var valor = $(this).val();
  // Verifica os cinco últimos caracteres
  if (valor.slice(-5) === '+++++') {
    // Se é igual executa uma ação
    console.log('ENVIAR FORMULARIO');
    console.log('+------------------------------+');
    console.log('PRODUTO: '+$("#nome").val());
    console.log('VALOR  : '+$("#valor").val());
    console.log('CÓDIGO : '+$("#codigo").val());
    console.log('+------------------------------+');
    $("input[type='text']").val('');
    // $("form").submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="teste" method="post">
  <div>Nome</div>
  <input type="text" id="nome" />
  <div>Valor</div>
  <input type="text" id="valor" />
  <div>Código</div>
  <input type="text" id="codigo" />
  <input type="button" value="enviar" id="btnEnviar" />
</form>
```

#### Referência

- [Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)